# Why does ChatGPT chat completion respond with different answers (temperature = 0)

Tags: chatgpt-api

I am helping a legal firm implementing a chatbot to help them answer legal questions.
Based on the question, we will figure out what parts of the civil codes are relevant, and create a prompt with the question and the relevant content.

My problem:
If I ask the same question a couple of times, the answers vary. In most cases they are still good but sometimes the answer is not taking into account all context and the answer is wrong.
I checked the prompt in all cases and the prompt is allways the same. The answer varies. While I set the temperature to 0.

is this inherent to what llm's are? I would appreciate some angles I missed

my code:

```
const axiosPromise = axios.post(
        openAiUrl,
        {
            model: gpt-3.5-turbo-16k,
            messages: prompt,
            max_tokens: maxTokens,
            temperature: 0
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + openAiApiKey
            }
        }
    );
```

I already tried multiple variations on temperature: 0, 0.0 or 0.1 all the same
I tries using top-p but that also didnt help

Comment: Currently observing the same behaviour with azure gpt-3.5-turbo.

Comment: I am also having this issue even with GPT 4.0, with temperature set to `0`. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No I didn't. I changed the design of my solutions to not rely to much on determinism with gpt.

Answer (score 0):

Found this about v4 api. I guess the same is true for 3.5 (to some degree)
The GPT-4 API is hosted with a backend that does batched inference. Although some of the randomness may be explained by other factors, the vast majority of non-determinism in the API is explainable by its Sparse MoE architecture failing to enforce per-sequence determinism.

[source](https://152334h.github.io/blog/non-determinism-in-gpt-4/#:%7E:text=The%20GPT%2D4%20API%20is,to%20enforce%20per%2Dsequence%20determinism.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee you'll get the same answer twice in a row with temperature = 0. But to avoid mistakes I would strongly suggest you to use GPT 4 and not 3.5. Especially in Chat mode. 3.5 turbo is more prone to mistakes than GPT 4 which would eventually change the answer too but it is usually more on the subject and accurate. The drawback is that GPT-4 is not for free unfortunately. The last version (the future GPT-4 turbo now in preview) is even better and faster.

Comment: Seed parameter of GPT 4 turbo solves it for me for now